# AppleOS Terminal to MS Command Prompt translation

Tags: windows, shell, terminal

How do I translate the Terminal command

```
pdf2txt.py -o filename.txt -t tag filename.pdf
```

for the Command Prompt on a Windows machine?

Comment: Why do you think it would be any different?

Comment: You're right. It's the same thing; I just had to point to the correct path to pdf2txt.py. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The commands are arguments passed to the pdf2txt.py script and they depend on the code inside the file, not on any terminal/command prompt constraints. So, the code remains exactly the same